# If $\alpha$ is an even permutation, prove that $\alpha^{-1}$ is an even permutation.

Tags: proof-verification, permutations

If $\alpha$ is an even permutation, prove that $\alpha^{-1}$ is an even permutation. If $\alpha$ is an odd permutation prove that $\alpha^{-1}$ is an odd permutation

Let the permutation $\alpha$ be a product of two cycles, if the permutation is even the transposition is $\alpha=\{T_1T_2 \cdots T_m\}$ if and only if $m$ is even. An inverse permutation $\alpha^{-1}$ is $\{T_1T_2 \cdots T_m\}^{-1}$. Now the transposition $T=T^{-1}$ thus the permutation and inverse permutation are equal so $\alpha=\alpha^{-1}$ if $m$ is even then $\alpha^{-1}$ is also even. Repeat the same process for odd.

Comment: Do you know about crossing numbers?

Comment: "Thus the permutation and the inverse permutation are equal"  This is incorrect.  Remember your socks-and-shoes principle.  You put on your socks and then you put on your shoes.  To reverse this process you must first remove your shoes before removing your socks.  In context, $(f\circ g)^{-1}=g^{-1}\circ f^{-1}$.  Now, note that transpositions do not necessarily commute.

Comment: You *can* however note that $\alpha^{-1}=T_m^{-1}T_{m-1}^{-1}\cdots T_2^{-1}T_1^{-1}$ and continue from there.  It is worth also citing (*or proving*) the theorem that all representations of $\alpha$ will simultaneously be even or will simultaneously be odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $\alpha = \sigma_1\sigma_2\dots \sigma_{2k}$, where $\sigma_i$ is transposition then $\alpha^{-1} = \sigma_{2k}\dots \sigma_2\sigma_1$.

Similarly with the case of odd permutation.

Answer (score 2):

If you are familiar with the $\text{sgn}$ function,

$$\text{sgn}: (S_n, \circ) \to (\{-1,1\}, .): \phi \mapsto 
\begin{cases} 
1 & \mathrm{if}\,\mathrm{\phi \ even} \\
-1 & \mathrm{if}\,\mathrm{\phi \ odd},
\end{cases}$$

you know that $\text{sgn}(\phi \circ \psi) = \text{sgn}(\phi)\cdot\text{sgn}(\phi)$.

Now, the result follows nicely using the following logic. Because the identity permutation is an even permutation, we have, if $\alpha$ is an even permutation,

$$1 = \text{sgn}(\text{id}) = \text{sgn}(\alpha \circ \alpha^{-1}) = \text{sgn}(\alpha)\cdot\text{sgn}(\alpha^{-1}) = \text{sgn}(\alpha^{-1})$$

such that $\alpha^{-1}$ is even, as desired.

The other statement is proven in the same way.